# How do I hide a modal when the overlay is clicked in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to hide the div which is the overlay only when the overlay is clicked and not any of its children (ie: the content):

```
modal.addEventListener('click', destroy, false);


function destroy(e) {
    if (e.target.id === overlay.id) {
        window.location.reload(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about checking if the clicked target is contained by the overlay? `overlay.contains(e.target)`?

Comment: check if overlay is clicked then set the CSS of modal to `display = 'none'`

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition is working but you don't hide something. For that you could add a class (for example `.hidden`) and define for that class `display: none`.

**Working example:**

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('#modal');
const overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay');

modal.addEventListener('click', destroy, false);

function destroy(e) {
  if (e.target.id === overlay.id) {
    e.target.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <div id="overlay">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```